# multiply text value and display answer jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to multiply a value that is already generated using jquery, but a static value.  I have done this when the value is coming from a text box, just not from a span tag.

The script below works when taking value from a textbox.  How can I modify this to read teh

Here is what I have so far:

HTML
This is the file that I want to multiply static value by

```
<p id="sum" name="equip_amount_four"></p>
```

This is the place I want to place the answer of the static value by the html above

```
<p>$ <span id="equipPymnt" name="equip_payment"></span></p>
```

jQuery

```
<script>
var multiplyShares = function() {
    var val1 = parseFloat($('#shares').val())
    var val2 = .086667

    val3 = val1 * val2 || "Invalid number"
    $("#result").html(val3.toFixed(2))
}

$("#shares").keyup(function() { multiplyShares(); });           
</script>
```

Comment: @Pranav: `;` is optional in JavaScript (unfortunately).

Comment: For other elements than `input`, `select` and `textarea`, use `.text()` or `.html()` instead of `.val()`. Just remember to parse it properly.

Comment: Right. Other DOM elements don't have a `value` property. @MelancialUK, answers go down there \/ . :-)

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: @isherwood made my comment shorter. :)

Comment: `var value = $('#sum').text(); $('#equipPymnt').text(newValue);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a few mismatched IDs in your HTML. The following works:

```js
var multiplyShares = function() {
  var val1 = parseFloat($('#sum').text());
  var val2 = .086667;
  var val3 = val1 * val2;
  val3 = isNaN(val3) ? "Invalid number" : val3.toFixed(2);
  $("#equipPymnt").html(val3);
}
multiplyShares();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="sum" name="equip_amount_four">500</p>
<p>$ <span id="equipPymnt" name="equip_payment"></span></p>
```

Comment: THis is using a textbox, which I said I can't use.

Comment: @C.Coggins sorry I missed that. The updated code uses the `<p>` tag as the source of the data. The only question that might remain is how to trigger an update.